# Search for text inside a bunch of Photoshop files

Tags: search, software-rec, adobe-photoshop, desktop-search

I have hundreds of Photoshop files that contain text layers. Is there a way to search for text in these files?

Maybe a connector for Google desktop or Windows search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Java-based (and freely available) [PSD Parser](http://blog.alternativaplatform.com/en/2007/07/09/parser-psd-formata/) that you could use in another Java program to iterate over the layers of each file. I don't know however if the parser supports output of plaintext from the layers. Some elementary programming skills in Java should be enough to get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is [psdMind](http://psdMind.com?ref=superuser) which is exactly capable of what you are looking for.